# Compile a .cs file which is located in different folder of the disk from another .cs program

Tags: c#

i want to compile a .cs program which exist in some other folder on the disk and generate a .dll of it, using another .cs program or a console application or a window application. i tried using the following

```
using (StreamReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"path\Filename.cs"))
{
     textFile = textReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(textFile);
}
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(); 
ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler(); 
// add compiler parameters 
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize"; 
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false; 
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;             
compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false; 
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");  
// compile the code 
CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams,        textFile);
```

Comment: Guys you made a real mess with all the edits here.

Comment: So in a nutshell, you want to compile a `.cs` file from C#? So what isn't working?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, sorry, I didn't see the closing using, I though the OP forgot a }

Comment: @Adrian more annoying IMO is "I" that became "i" due to [bad suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/281166) merged with the one who improved it (who is you, lol.. you missed the smallification of the "I") - can't blame anyone, just suggest to wait for a while before jumping on the edit wagon. :)

Comment: For the code above where does the .dll sit after compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have idea something like this till you don't find something concrete try this

```
Process processCS= new Process();
processCS.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\<your code directory>";
processCS.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework\version\csc.exe   /out:yourdllname.dll yourcodefilename.cs";
processCS.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processCS.Start();
processCS.WaitForExit();
```

You can call this from on cs file to compile other cs file. Check if it works .... \

By default process will search the files in system32 dir so use the following code to do that...

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe");
info.Arguments = @" /out:C:\ss\Class1.dll C:\ss\Class1.cs";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(info);
```

In argument i have given path of cs file as C:\ss\Class1.cs    you give according to your path but keep in mind give small path.

Comment: it is not working it says cannot find specified path. in 3rd line what is <yourcode directory> mean.

Comment: debug and check the path its taking and change the path accordingly it will work

Comment: change the path according to you file location.. this you can do right... i dont have windows in my machine now so i cant execute and send you the code... i can go home and do that... for that you need to wait... but if you debug the code and change accrodingly it will work

Comment: Process processCS = new Process(); processCS.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Documents and Settings\a511510\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tasks\wsdl1\wsdl1";               processCS.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:library Program.cs"; processCS.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;             processCS.Start();                                              processCS.WaitForExit();

Comment: my cs file is located in different directory, i want to compile that to get respective .dll. i am not understanding <your code directory> .and what is yourcodefilename.cs. clearly to say i have 1 console program wen i press F5 i want that program to compile another .cs program located some where and generate .dll

Comment: awesome man nice work i am able to do it. hey can u help me in one more thing in your code we specify the name of the program to be compiled at run time. if the same program name is not known and compiler should execute the program which is in that directory of type .cs

Comment: hey can u help me in one more thing. Now i am gettin .dll of that file , i want to refer that dll during run time and not using add references.

Comment: [DllImport(@"<Full Path and dllname>")]
 public static extern void functionyouwanttocall(parameters);

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code to refer that .dll and create instance of the class present in that.

Comment: Check this link will help you to do what you need

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13747/Dynamically-load-a-class-and-execute-a-method-in-N